# What is the difference between Benchmark and Workload concpets?

Tags: performance

I am confused between the meaning of benchmark and workload in computer science context. 
My understanding for both is the following:
Workload == the data or logs that generated to simulate users behavior on a specific system. 
Benchmark, the way of testing a piece of software to see how well the system is doing in term of performance.

Again, I might be totally wrong and I wish there will be somebody to clear my understanding of these concepts.

Sincerely

Comment: Define "concpets".

Comment: Are they similar? Are they different in CS field? I read papers and these two words(workload, and benchmark) came often but I still do not fully understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meanings of these terms depend on the context.

The term *benchmark* as a noun could mean any of the following:

- A computer program or a collection of programs.
- A quantifiable metric or a collection of quantifiable metrics.
- An evaluation or measurement of a metric by running a program.
- A collection of workloads (programs)

The term *benchmark* as a verb means to to measure a metric or a collection of metrics by running a program or a collection or programs, possibly repeatedly.

The terms *benchmarking* and *benchmark testing* are synonyms. In the term *benchmark testing*, the term *benchmark* refers to a metric, not a program. When the purpose of benchmarking is to evaluate performance (execution time or throughput), the term *performance testing* means the same thing.

The term *workload* could mean any of the following:

- A single benchmark (a computer program or application)
- A collection of benchmarks (a collection of computer programs).
- A benchmark and the input provided to it.

As you might imagine, the two terms in be used together. A *workload benchmark* can mean either an evaluation of a collection of programs or a collection of programs. A *benchmark workload* refers to a collection of programs used for a particular evaluation. The term *workload benchmark testing* refers to evaluating a collection of a programs.

The goal of benchmarking is to compare systems or programs against either other.